# Add a <noscript> tag in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I would like to add `<body><noscript><h1>Please enable your javascript<h1></noscript></body>` in the developer mode.

I tried to configure it in the `nuxt.config.js` file but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to setup a `noscript` tag, you need to create an `app.html` in the root directory of your project as explained in [the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views#document-apphtml).

Like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    <noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that if you're using `ssr: true`, you will still get some content even if the JS is disabled because the content will be generated on the server for some parts.