# How to initialize the attribute of html elements when using nuxt-link or router-link in NuxtJS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have two pages `index` and `blog` and I want to manipulate the attribute of `html` before the rendering of each page, such as setting `<html>` to `<html class="dark">`, so I implement a method `initDOM()` and call it inside the vue `mounted` hook function. When I use `<a></a>` to navigate pages, everything works well. The function is:

```js
initDOM() {
  let htmlObj = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
  htmlObj[0].setAttribute('class', 'dark')
}
```

However, when I use `<nuxt-link></nuxt-link>` to navigate pages, the DOM tree is not initialized by my `initDOM()` function. I found that it seems because when I use `<a></a>`, the whole DOM tree is refreshed when going into a new webpage, but the DOM tree is not refreshed when using `<nuxt-link></nuxt-link>`. Although replacing `<nuxt-link>` by `<a>` works well, the loading time is obviously longer than using `<nuxt-link>`

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: As you can guess, nuking your SPA with an `a` tag is not the good approach. Also, you're not supposed to manipulate the DOM directly while using Vue/Nuxt. Can't you do your thing with a state? You can access the initial `html` [via `app.html`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71825071/8816585). Nvm, that one is for Nuxt2 and is a bit more tricky for Nuxt3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I use Nuxt3... My situation is that when the user has chosen the dark theme, the theme will be strangely reset to `light` after clicking `<nuxt-link>`.  Thanks for your suggestion, now I solved it by implementing dark mode using `pinia`! It seems that maybe this problem a bug of `@nuxtjs/color-mode`. I will open an issue on GitHub once I get a minimal reproducible example. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Glad I helped somehow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP solved the issue by using Pinia, so that it could have a successfully working dark mode.