# Nuxt 2: how can i ban Google No translate?

Tags: nuxt.js, google-translate

Hello i try google stops to ask for translate in Nuxt 2 (SSR).

I add this to the nuxt config.

```js
head: {
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'es',
      class: ['notranslate'],
      translate: 'no',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'google', content: 'notranslate' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }

    ],
    bodyAttrs: {
      class: ['notranslate'],
    },
}
```

But Nuxt only renders translate: no on the html (no class, no meta google). And this doesn't stops Google translate. Anyone knows how can I render this tags to the html?

Render the tags and atributes in the html.

Comment: Obviously I add theis code in the head part. Without any success.

Comment: Is `notranslate` a thing actually? Never saw that one before. You could use an [`app.html`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71825071/8816585) if you want to add something to your `html` tag.

Comment: Hi @kissu Is taked from here and other posts : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61363117/15012668](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61363117/15012668)